# New instance of class in a shared memory segment C++

Tags: c++, boost, ipc, shared-memory

I'm actually trying to step-up in thread, process and shared memory in C++ but I'm actually stuck with my Inter Process Communication.

I decided to use a message queue cause i already used some in past project but never with multiple process.

Here is my problem, I can't get register events from different process. I think that initialize my message queue in a share memory segment would fix the problem but I can't figure out how to "force" the new instance of my class to be in my shared memory segment

Because I start with shared memory in C++, I use [boost Simple Exemple](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html)

Ideally what i would like to have would be something like :

```
int main (void)
{
    shared_memory_object shm (open_or_create, "MySharedMemory", read_write);

    // initialise shm using boost Simple Exemple

    shmPtr = region.get_address();

    // initialise message queue named msgQueue in my shared memory segment

    msgQueuePtr = &msgQueue;

}
```

At the end, shmPtr would be equal to msgQueuePtr.
Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Look into placement new

Comment: The usual problem with shared memory is you can't store pointers as the address space of the two process will differ.  So what's a valid pointer in one process will be an invalid pointer in the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create new C++ object at specific memory address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554774/create-new-c-object-at-specific-memory-address/1554796)

Comment: @MikeVine the point of Boost Interprocess is to hide those mechanics

Comment: Ok @MikeVine i'll check that. thanks

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it should, thanks for the link, because i'm a bit hurry (the end of my project is on sunday), i'll check that just after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a managed memory segment so you can "just" construct your types in shared memory (note: be sure they are POD or take a shared-memory allocator to properly handle any dynamic allocation/reference).

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct MyQueue { /* */ };

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

int main() {
    bip::managed_shared_memory msm(bip::open_or_create, "test", 10ul<<30); // 10 MiB
    MyQueue& q = *msm.find_or_construct<MyQueue>("queue_instance")();
}
```

Here's a bigger demo complete with a queue implementation + locking etc. [Boost shared memory and synchronized queue issue/crash in consumer process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509815/boost-shared-memory-and-synchronized-queue-issue-crash-in-consumer-process)

### BONUS

Boost Interprocess has a complete message_queue implementation: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue.html

So, when in doubt, I suggest to use that.

Comment: I didn't know that  boost has a message_queue already, thanks for the info, i'll use this one  for the moment. I might come back later on (when my project will have ended) to give a try at the other method you gave me.
Thanks a lot